# asp.net mvc static selectlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Still trying to rap my head around mvc/EF/razor. I have a static/hard-coded drop down list. I want to "bind" this to a non-enumerable model entity "status".

In the view I have

```
@Html.DropDownList("status", String.Empty)
```

In the controller, I have

```
ViewBag.status = new SelectList(new[] { "yes", "no", "maybe" }, booking.status);
```

I suspect if status was enumerable, I would be done, but I get the following error since status is not enumerable.

There is no `ViewData` item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the key 'status'.

I'm clearly misssing some things and greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like your array initialization - that compiles?  Try this:

```
ViewBag.status = new SelectList(new string[] { "yes", "no", "maybe" }, booking.status);
```

You need to pass the select list to the HtmlHelper.DropDownList method call ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("status", ( SelectList )ViewBag.status)
```

Comment: thanks. That does not seem to solve the issue. I get the same error. 

Note: To get the view to run, I had to cast the viewbag item like this...

@Html.DropDownList("status", (SelectList) ViewBag.status)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, cast is needed as the ViewBag property is dynamic and therefore untyped.